# How to convert a Hair mesh into Poly Hair?

Tags: mesh, hair

Im using a hair data set that consist of many hair models of 10.000 strands each, i called one Hair Model into blender with an script and blender created the Hair mesh, later i turned the complete hair mesh into curves by selecting the mesh and clicking on object>convert>curve, now i want to extrude thouse curves to make a Poly Hair but i dont know how to select the curves in order to extrude it without Blender crashing? how small should i make the circle in order to extrude correctly the curves?

[image]

[image]

should i separate the curves since after converting the mesh into curves it created only une curve mesh?
[image]

Update:

I got to see that if i select some strands and sepparate from the complete mesh with P is easier for blender to extrude the strands
[image]
Second Update: after extruding the mayority of the hair the quantity of polygons is too much and requires too much Computer resources that result in many Blender crashes on the process of extruding . My Question is how can i diminish the processing charge in order for Blender no to crash? there is a way to diminish the strands number or a way to mix some strands into one so it can have less process impact?
[image]

Comment: Do you want to convert the strands into hair curves? Something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uH85f.jpg)?

Comment: Yes exactly, i want to extrude it. When i call the data set and turn it to a mesh with the script, this mesh is one strand mesh. After i select it and turn it into curves with Object>Convert>Curve it gets this spongy look on edit mode (second image). Later i added a circle,selected some strands and added that circle on Object Data Properties>Bevel>Object. The problem is that Blender crash after i do that and i think thats because im not selecting correctly the strands and blender is still trying to extrude the mesh with 10 strands completely. Can you point what im doing wrong?

Comment: You need to reduce the number of imported hair strands and their number of vertices. This can be done in the script or manually. In my experiments, I've reduced it to only 5 vertices per strand. If it's too blocky you can use a *Subdivision Surface* modifier. In the Curve settings, there is also a setting to lower the resolution. That way it doesn't generate that much geometry. I can show you an example later if you need.